# conditions on antd input field if written specific thing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, antd

New react hook programmer. Here i have antd form, everything is fine except need some kind of checking on input, my question is, if user writes on 'businesId' input field, for example '1234' then need to check from an api, if it is used before then cannot continue with form, but if it is not used before then its fine to continue. From api i'm getting an array of objects where is 'businesId'. My code :

```html
 <div>
      <Form.Item label={"name"} name="name">
        <Input type="string" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label={"businesId"} name="businessId">
        <Input type="string" />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          {"submit"}
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </div>
```

```js
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState();
    const api = useContext(ApiContext);

  
   useEffect(() => {
    api.custApi.apiCustGet().then((res) => {
      setOrders(res);
    });
  }, [api.custApi]);
    console.log(orders);
```

Comment: `for example '1234' then need to check from an api`: What will be the minimum length of `businesId` to trigger the API?
`if it is used before then cannot continue with form`: Means submit button will be disabled?

Comment: I dont know the minimum can we just take something ? Yes submit button will be disabled(or have any other way?)

Comment: Obviously, we can take something. Then if the user presses a key the your API will called. Is it OK for you?

Comment: Obviously it needs to be called if needs to check from there ? Or do we have other way ? Can it also give some message for example ”you cannot use same id more than once”?

Comment: Provide sample data after `apiCustGet` API call

Comment: would be something like : [{name: "james", businessId: "123456"}, {name: "alex", businessId: "54732"}]

Comment: Hey @walee, check out my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to show success message after form submit is successfull, for example user clicks submit button then comes a message ’successfully added cust’ and it stays there for 2 seconds ?

Comment: Done. Check. And next time please add all your requirement at once in the question. Don't tail or prolong your requirement like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified BusinessId `Form.Item`:

```
<Form.Item label={"businesId"} name="businessId">
    <Input
        type="string"
        disabled={loading}
        onChange={(e) => handleInput(e.target.value)}
    />
    {isInvalidBusinessId ? (
        <span className="error-text">{errorMessage}</span>
    ) : null}
</Form.Item>
```

`handleInput` function:

```
function handleInput(value) {
    setIsInvalidBusinessId(false);
    if (value.length) {
      setLoading(true);
      // You will call api.custApi.apiCustGet() here
      if (orders.filter((f) => f.businessId === value).length) {
        setIsInvalidBusinessId(true);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

**Edit:**

To show success message on form submit:

```
const onFinish = (values) => {
    // You determine your success logic here
    setIsSubmitSuccess(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsSubmitSuccess(false);
    }, 2000); // Two seconds interval
  };
```

**Result:**

For detail see working solution at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-antd4150-forked-4tet5?file=/index.js).

[image]

Comment: inside '  const onFinish = (values) ' i have also '      .then(() => history.replace("/somewhere"));' for some reason this timeout even it is 9 seconds it only works for one second ' setIsSubmitSuccess(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsSubmitSuccess(false);
    }, 9000); '
'

Comment: You are using `setTimeout` in the wrong way. Write your `onFinish` code block. I'll fix that.

Comment: hey i checked from net 'Business ID consists of seven digits, a dash and a control mark, for example 1234567-8.' so if we implement that to this would it be something like 'acceptableBusinessID = /^[0-9]{7}-{1}[0-9]{1}$/g;'

Comment: at the moment it is rendering api everytime, i read from somewhere  'Business ID consists of seven digits, a dash and a control mark', could we put some length ?

Comment: Recheck the demo link.

Comment: getting 'undefined' on businessId now

Comment: name input is working but on businessId i'm getting 'undefined'

Comment: i think 'onChange' is working differently with antd Input

Comment: See the latest link with different implementation and it works.

Comment: getting on budinessId still 'undefined', but no problem with my other inputs which does not use onchange

Comment: hey found the problem when i delete this it works   {isInvalidBusinessId ? (
        <span className="error-text">{errorMessage}</span>
    ) : null}, how can i keep that and still have this working ?

Comment: Follow the demo carefully. I've deleted `span` tag and added rules.

Comment: it is not working if i have two with the same 'text' but different 'value' like this  { value: "6", text: "Cancelled" },
    { value: "7", text: "Cancelled" }

Comment: @ZynayedShahriar it will chose one of them (user cant pick from those)